# Hot to add a war dependency in maven without having it overlayed

Tags: java, maven, war

We are developing a Java web application to be deployed as a war file in Tomcat9.

We want to have some other war files that need to be deployed separate war files due to the system architecture. They are commercial and out of my control.

I want to have this separate wars added in the pom as runtime, so pom we use to deploy the application knows that they are needed and deploys also any war dependency i the webapps dir.

The problem I have is that in the moment I include this war runtime dependencies, the package phase add them as overlays to our war application file.

What I want is to avoid having this war files added as overlays to our war file.

I have found no reference on how to avoid that maven behavior.

I can't share the real pom files due to NDA constraints. This is a incomplete example of what I have build now.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>myOrg</groupId>
        <artifactId>myApp</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>myApp-war</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>internal-app-war</name>
    <version>2.8</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.exampleorg</groupId>
            <artifactId>ExampleA</artifactId>
            <type>war</type>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.exampleorg</groupId>
            <artifactId>ExampleB</artifactId>
            <type>war</type>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            All jar dependencies with compile scope
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Can any one propose a way to achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you reproduce this behavior with two toy projects you can share?

Comment: I will try. Will take some time. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misusing `<dependencies>` here.

If you want to make sure that other WARs are deployed on the same server, then you need to manage that outside of Maven, e.g. with Puppet/Chef/... or through a docker container.

Maven dependencies are only meant for the build itself.

Comment: Would Scope system do?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Why have a dependency in the first place? For WAR dependencies, I only know two use cases: 1. Overlays 2. Pack it into an EAR. If you just want to deploy it on some Application server, why have a dependency?

Comment: I don’t know.  Hence the “can you make an example of what you want to do” question.  Otherwise I agree, this is probably an X-Y question.

Comment: Good copy. I will need a different way to deploy the war files. I wanted to use maven because it's very convenient to have everything in a single configuration file. Thanks.

Comment: @JavierVilarroig Multi-WAR files-knowing-each-other deployment is what EAR files are for.  This requires more from the deployment environment.   Problem is again what exactly it is you want to do.

Comment: Thanks @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I will investigate this topic.

Comment: @JavierVilarroig you need to understand the technology better to do these things right instead of even considering things as in this question . I suggest you read up on the servlet specification and the web profile bit of the EE specification.